# Find an optimizer for $g(x,y)$ if it exists

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

Consider $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}_{0} \to \mathbb{R}_{0}$ such that $f(x,y)$ is a continuous function and satisfies the following properties:

1. $f(x,y) = f(y,x)$
2. $f(tx,ty) = tf(x,y) \ \forall \ t > 0 $
3. $f(1,1) = 1$

**Can we show that if $g(x,y) := 3f(x,y) - 2(x+y)$, then $\underset{x,y}{\text{argmax}}[g(x,y)] = (0,0)$ assuming a maximizer exists?**

I can only show that $g(x^{*},y^{*}) =0$ since otherwise $g(2x^{*},2y^{*}) > g(x,y)$ yields a contradiction if $g(x^{*}, y^{*}) \neq 0$. I can neither think of a counter-example nor a proof to complete the solution.

Note that $f$ is not necessarily (partially) differentiable. $\mathbb{R}_0$ is the set of non-negative reals.

Comment: How is condition 4 possible?

Comment: @user469053 Can you explain why?

Comment: Is this in reference to my original comment, which is now deleted?

Comment: @user469053 I'm asking why condition 4 is not possible. Thanks.

Comment: It says that $f(x,y) \geq f(z,w)$ if and only if $x\geq z$ and $y\geq w$. Choose $x>z$ and $y<w$. Then the condition $(x\geq z)\wedge (y\geq w)$ is not satisfied, and therefore the condition $f(x,y)\geqslant f(z,w)$ is not satisfied. Similarly, since $z<x$, the condition $(z\geq x)\wedge (w\geq y)$ is not satisfied, so the condition $f(z,w) \geq f(x,y)$ is not satisfied. Therefore $f(x,y)<f(z,w)$ and $f(z,w)<f(x,y)$.

Comment: @user469053 Thanks for pointing that out. I didn't see that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By conditions 2 and 3, $f(t,t)=t$ for all $t>0$. By continuity, $f(0,0)=\lim_{t\to 0^+} f(t,t)=\lim_{t\to 0^+}t=0$.  From this it follows that $g(0,0)=0$.

As you said, if $g$ has a maximizer, then the maximum value must be $0$. We also know that $g(0,0)=0$. So if we're interested in showing that $(0,0)$ is a maximizer, we're done. If we want to show that $(0,0)$ is the unique maximizer, then I think the result is not true. That is, we can have other maximizers.

Let $p=1/\log_2(3/2)\approx 1.709511$. For non-negative real $x,y$, define $$f(x,y)=\Bigl(\frac{|x|^p+|y|^p}{2}\Bigr)^{1/p}.$$  This function is continuous and satisfies conditions $1$-$3$.

Note that $$g(0,1)=3/2^{1/p}-2=3/2^{\log_2(3/2)}-2=3/(3/2)-2=0.$$ By symmetry and positive homogeneity, $g(t,0)=g(0,t)=0$ for all $t\geqslant 0$.

We will show that $g(x,y)<0$ for all $(x,y)$ with $x,y>0$. This will show that $g$ has a maximizer (and in fact, the set of all $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}_0^2$ with $\min \{x,y\}=0$ is the exact set of maximizers). Fix $x,y>0$. Define $t=x+y$ and $\theta=\frac{x}{x+y}$. So $$\theta(t,0)+(1-\theta)(0,t)=\frac{x}{x+y}(x+y,0) + \frac{y}{x+y}(0,x+y)=(x,y).$$ That is, $(x,y)$ is a convex combination of the points $(t,0)$ and $(0,t)$ with convex coefficients of $\theta$ and $1-\theta$. Note that $0<\theta, 1-\theta<1$.

Next we note that $$f(\theta (t,0)+(1-\theta)(0,t))<\theta f(t,0)+(1-\theta)f(0,t).$$ This follows from strict convexity of the $L_p$ norm for $1<p<\infty$ (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80139/why-is-the-l-p-norm-strictly-convex-for-1p-infty)). Therefore $$g(x,y)=3f(\theta (t,0)+(1-\theta)(0,t)) - 2(x+y) < 3\theta f(t,0)+3(1-\theta)f(0,t) - 2\theta t-2(1-\theta)t = \theta g(t,0)+(1-\theta)g(0,t)=0.$$